# Remove XML Node

Tags: xml, powershell, element

I have an XML file which contains a `<Notes>` node that I wish to remove.

```xml
<APPOrganisationUnits>
  <APPOrganisationUnitsRow num="1">
    <OrganisationId>TEST1</OrganisationId>
    <APPContactDetails>
      <APPContactDetailsRow num="1">
        <Notes>Notes 1</Notes>
      </APPContactDetailsRow>
      <APPContactDetailsRow num="2">
        <Notes>Notes 2</Notes>
      </APPContactDetailsRow>
      <APPContactDetailsRow num="3">
        <Notes>Notes 3</Notes>
      </APPContactDetailsRow>
    </APPContactDetails>
  </APPOrganisationUnitsRow>
  <APPOrganisationUnitsRow num="2">
    <OrganisationId>TEST2</OrganisationId>
    <APPContactDetails>
      <APPContactDetailsRow num="1">
        <Notes>Notes 1</Notes>
      </APPContactDetailsRow>
      <APPContactDetailsRow num="2">
        <Notes>Notes 2</Notes>
      </APPContactDetailsRow>
    </APPContactDetails>
  </APPOrganisationUnitsRow>
</APPOrganisationUnits>
```

For each instance of the `<notes>` node I just want to remove it. My code this which runs but does not remove the nodes.

```bsh
$XMLFile = "$Provider_Root\Processing\small.xml"
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $XMLFile)

foreach ($APPContactDetailsRow in $xml.APPOrganisationUnits.APPOrganisationUnitsRow.APPContactDetails) {
    if ($APPContactDetailsRow.Item('Notes')) {
        $APPContactDetailsRow.RemoveChild($_)
    }
}
$xml.Save($XMLFile)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current object variable (`$_`) isn't populated in the context of your loop. You need to put the child node into a variable before you can remove it. Also, Just because you name a variable after a particular type of nodes doesn't automagically enumerate the nodes via this variable. You need to actually expand the nodes.

Change this:

```bsh
foreach ($APPContactDetailsRow in $xml.APPOrganisationUnits.APPOrganisationUnitsRow.APPContactDetails) {
    if ($APPContactDetailsRow.Item('Notes')) {
        $APPContactDetailsRow.RemoveChild($_)
    }
}
```

into this:

```bsh
foreach ($APPContactDetailsRow in $xml.APPOrganisationUnits.APPOrganisationUnitsRow.APPContactDetails.APPContactDetailsRow) {
    $n = $APPContactDetailsRow.Item('Notes')
    if ($n) {
        $APPContactDetailsRow.RemoveChild($n)
    }
}
```

With that said, it'd probably be simpler to select the nodes with an [XPath expression](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon6.5.3/expressions.html) and use a pipeline for deleting them:

```bsh
$xml.SelectNodes('//AppContactDetailsRow/Notes') | ForEach-Object {
    $_.ParentNode.RemoveChild($_)
}
```

Comment: Both solutions have worked equally well for me but I will use the second method as it seems cleaner/shorter. Many thanks